# JSoup Element selection by CSS rule: is there any documented ordering?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am currently using JSoup CSS selection to get a list of some elements in an HTML document.

Though to verify the robustness of my algorithm I have to know in which order the elements do get browsed and, therefore, returned.

My concern is strictly linked to nested elements. If i do search for all the elements in a document which is like the following:

```
<div> Something <span style='color:red;'>special</span> for me </div>
```

and i run in JSoup:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myCode);
 Elements els = doc.select("*");
```

in which order will those two elements be traversed, and therefore returned? I am currently looking at the documentation page for the [select](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html#select%28java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.nodes.Element%29) method, but no information is provided on the traversal order. Is there any more precise reference I can look at? 
Clearly i can proceed in a trial-and-error to infer the ordering, but I would like to know if this is already known/someone has already digged into it, since I do not know the HTML structure of the documents I have to parse beforehand.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you have a `p` tag inside another `p` tag? That makes no sense,

Comment: It was just an example to make a quick question about the traversal order. Since it matters for the reader, I have made a better one :)

Comment: How do you exactly mean "which order will those two elements be returned"? The `Elements` object is returned, that contains the two `Element` objects. Simplified, when Jsoup traverses the document, it will read each char into a buffer and tokenize it and compare to the tags. There is a class `HtmlTreeBuilder` which then builds a DOM tree from the tokens. A stack is used to keep order of parents/children, which is implemented in the class `DescendableLinkedList`. I suggest you look into the source code at https://github.com/jhy/jsoup to learn more.

Comment: I see. This indicates that it uses a depth-first traversal. 
With more digging in the source code, i have seen that the `select` method eventually calls in the `Collector` class, which involves a `NodeTraversor` class, which uses a stack aswell.
I have then looked at sources of the `NodeTraversor` class which explicitly says that it performs a Depth-first traversal.